# Frenchman claims new victim

Tags: knowledge, visual, language

A notorious French contract killer has taken another high-profile victim. The following clues describe the time of year of the attack, the weapon used, the place in which the hit was made, and the victim's identity. The answers can be used to find out the **first name of the suspect**.

**1. The time**

> [image]

**2. The weapon**

> [image]
>   <sub>Image credit: The McClouds, CC-BY-SA 2.0</sub>

**3. The place**

> [image]

**4. The victim**

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The weapon (@Chrone got it):

> <s>Welcome mat, Ché Guevarra --> Bienvenu chez (french). The initial 'w' of welcome is cut off?</s> 
>  More likely what @Chrone said: Ché in a mat --> machet(e), the final 'e' is missing.

The place:

> Looks like 'dar es-salaam' (arabic) but mirror image, and in pieces. Broken mirror? Also the final 'm' is missing.

The victim (@OmegaKrypton's hint)

> Looks like a periodic table: aha! The columns are element names. Arsenic Holmium Silicon Hassium Caesium Tantalum Tellurium. <s>The fourth letter of each</s> If you spelled them vertically from the top then the letters in red spell EMISSAR(Y), final 'y' is missing.

The time: see @BladeWraith's hint and @olim's answer

> If I got the final answer right (see below), the missing letter is an R, and OP says "time of year", then I guess <s>SUMMER, so the word to fill in is --S-U--M-M-E- ??? HAS CUTE MOMENT ??? Oh wait, WINTER works too, duh... --W-I--N-T-E- ??? DOWN IN ANOTHER ??? (random guesses)</s> nope, wayyy off :-) As @olim explains, it's DECEMBE(R). The missing letter is indeed R.

Whodunnit:

> The missing letters are _EMY, well if he's french, then probably RÉMY.

Comment: I think you may be overthinking the weapon one. Maybe it’s simply rot13(“Pur” va “zng”, juvpu lvryqf “Znpurg(r)” naq gur “r” vf jung zvffvat.) I might be completely wrong though.

Comment: @Chrone - yeah that sounds more likely!

Comment: It's not the fourth letter, but if you spelled them vertically from the top then it would be the letters in red

Comment: The date looks like keys on a keyboard/piano...

Comment: sorry, the time, not date looks like keys on a piano, although can't figure out what it says if thats the case

Comment: @BladeWraith, that's an interesting idea. The first appearance of the first six numbers spells out DECEBE. That looks like December without the R. I don't know how the encoding would work with the sharps and for letters after G but definitely some potential...

Comment: All correct! Well done, everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Partial

4. The victim

> seems like the right half of the periodic table

Answer (score 4):

Partial

1. Time of Year (thanks to @Blade Wraith)

> December. It is indeed a piano keyboard with the trios of numbers indicating chords. e.g. first letter is D F# A which is a D major chord. All are major chords except the 4th which is E minor giving 'Em' and therefore spelling 'DECEmBE(r)'. There is no R, consistent with @deep thought's answer.

Comment: This must be it. Well spotted, and welcome to puzzling.SE!